# Leave default option value empty in html select

Tags: html, html-select, default-value

I have an html select that is populated with DATA from a query using a foreach loop. It looks something like this

```
$client = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT string FROM `file` WHERE 
`code` = 002 AND `status` = 2");

echo 'Filter by client: ';
  echo '<select name="client_list">';
  foreach ($client as $key => $row) {
    $value = $row->string;
    echo 
  '<option value='.$value.'>'
  .$value. '</option>';
  }
  $client = $_GET['client_list'];
  echo '</select>';
```

It serves as a filter to display data based on the selected option value. The table that it filters looks somehting like this

```
   |client  | file              | 
   |------  |-------------------|
   |client1 | file00000         |
   |client2 | file00002         |
```

Now I want to make the first option value (the default value)  of the html empty. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
      $client = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT string FROM `file` WHERE 
     `code` = 002 AND `status` = 2");

    echo 'Filter by client: ';
    echo '<select name="client_list"><option value=""></option>';
    foreach ($client as $key => $row) {
        $value = $row->string;
        echo 
       '<option value='.$value.'>'
        .$value. '</option>';
    }
    $client = $_GET['client_list'];
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: That gives two empty values. You're missing / in option.

Comment: @R1ddler You wrote *"That gives two empty values. You're missing / in option"* - So I for one am confused by that comment and whether or not it does solve the question completely and doesn't have anything to do with your new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/46588904/1415724

Comment: If you ommit the closing / in option, that does give two empty values. This solved the question, I only needed to add / to option and it worked. My new question is different from this one and has nothing to do with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Add an empty option first:

```
echo '<select name="client_list"><option value=""></option>';
```

on submit if `client_list` is empty you know someone didn't choose anything.

Comment: That works to create an empty value but when I hit submit, it doesn't give the desired results. When I submit with empty client list I want to display a clean unfiltered query but instead it doesn't give me any results.

Comment: that is another question than original. You should not use the `$client = $_GET['client_list'];` in your query if its empty