# How to show selected option value after submit

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have an html select that is populated with data from a query using a foreach loop. The default value is empty, so when the page loads, it displays an unfiltered query. It looks something like this

```
$client = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT string FROM `file` WHERE 
`code` = 001");

echo 'Filter by client: ';
  echo '<select name="client_list"><option value=""></option>';
  foreach ($client as $key => $row) {
    $value = $row->string;
    echo 
  '<option value='.$value.'>'
  .$value. '</option>';
  }
  $client = $_GET['client_list'];
  echo '</select>';
```

It serves as a filter to display data based on the selected option value. The table that it filters looks something like this

```
   |client  | file              | 
   |------  |-------------------|
   |client1 | file00000         |
   |client2 | file00002         |
```

Now when I hit submit and see the filtered query results which are correct, I also see the default option value instead of the one selected to filter the data in the html select. How can I fix [this](https://gyazo.com/7af8ad8e5bf108ac0970025535562f0a)?

Comment: didn't you already (sort of) posted this already? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46582289/1415724 and accepted an answer.

Comment: It's not the same question. It's related to the same problem, but it's a different question.

Comment: _It's not the same question_ It is almost 100% the same question

Comment: [Consult this comment...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582289/leave-default-option-value-empty-in-html-select#comment80131622_46582404) under the other question/answer. I feel it is a duplicate post.

Comment: If it was the same question, I wouldn't have asked twice. I accepted the answer from the other question. The question was how to have the default option value empty on page load when you have the select filled with query data. This question is about how to display the value that is selected after the form has been submitted. How on earth is that the same? Yes it's the same file, the same html select and the same query but the question is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retain the value from your $_POST var and then add the selected attribute to retain and have it set to that selected value:

```
echo 'Filter by client: ';
  echo '<select name="client_list"><option value=""></option>';
  foreach ($client as $key => $row) {
    $value = $row->string;
    if($_GET['client_list'] == $value){ 
       echo '<option value='.$value.' selected>'.$value. '</option>';
    }else{
       echo '<option value='.$value.'>'.$value. '</option>';
    }
  $client = $_GET['client_list'];
  echo '</select>';
```

Comment: I'm using $_GET request not $_POST.

Comment: Then change $_POST to $_GET, should be simple.